# Pantehon mail closing on its own when performing an action

Tags: pantheon-mail

Having an issue with Mail closing on its own randomly. Using a Gmail account. Typically it happens after performing an action, like deleting an email.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/back-up-geary-mail-profile-linux/

Read and think. This is the same app in Elementary OS, they just renamed it. You can remove the profile in the terminal using a command sudo rm - rf
Read the link I provided. You have a location provided there. This program is really piece of junk, because it is not able to handle large size messages especially with large attachments. Reconsider to get rid of this via sudo apt remove - -purge appnameinelementary Use Mozilla Thunderbird instead. Tested. No issues.